# What is the exact limit of $a_n=-\frac1e+e^{(\frac1e)^{...^{\frac{1}{e^n}}}}$ for $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, integers

Some analysis and computation in wolfram alpha show that sequence $a_n=-\frac1e+e^{(\frac1e)^{...^{\frac{1}{e^n}}}}$ could be close to integer exactly $2$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2Fe+%2Be%5E(1%2Fe)%5E(1%2Fe%C2%B2)%5E(1%2Fe%5E3)%5E(1%2Fe%5E4)%5E(1%2Fe%5E5)%5E(1%2Fe%5E6)%5E(1%2Fe%5E7)%5E(1%2Fe%5E8)%5E(1%2Fe%5E9)%5E(1%2Fe%5E10)) for $n$ even and for $n$ is odd it gives approximately 1.135.. , Now in that case I'm mixed to predict its limit , then I should say the limit is not exact , But probably i will have a luck to get limit close to $2$, then my question here is :

> > **Question:**
> >     What is the exact limit of $a_n=-\frac1e+e^{(\frac1e)^{...^{\frac{1}{e^n}}}}$ for $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: I think the definition would be clearer if you wrote down more terms, which can be done more conveniently using the [arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation). Is it $-\frac{1}{e} + e \uparrow \frac{1}{e} \uparrow \frac{1}{e^2} \uparrow \frac{1}{e^3} \uparrow \ldots \uparrow \frac{1}{e^n}$ assuming that $\uparrow$ is right-associative?